# How to listen all queue in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, redis, laravel-5.3

laravel 5.4 + redis

If I use `php artisan queue:listen` , it will listen the default queue.
If I specify the queue by `php artisan queue:listen --queue a`then only the queue a will be listen.
Is there anyway to listen all queue in laravel 5.4 if there are many queues?

Comment: Now I can use "php artisan queue:listen --queue a,b,c" to listen more than one queue, but I still don't know how to listen all of it .

Answer (score 5):

I am afraid you cannot listen to all available queues without specifying which ones; you can, however, use the `--queue` parameter for multiple queues, e.g.,:

```
php artisan queue:listen --queue a,b,c
```